# I am using Progress 4gl and trying to dynamically change a column-label, is this possible

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I tried the below code :

```
def temp-table tt-dg1
    field dtoday as date column-label "dg "
    .

buffer tt-dg1:BUFFER-FIELD("dtoday"):
column-LABEL = buffer tt-dg1:BUFFER-FIELD("dtoday"):column-LABEL + "77".

display buffer tt-dg1:BUFFER-FIELD("dtoday"):column-LABEL.

create tt-dg1.
dtoday = today.

display tt-dg1 with frame f2.
```

Expecting field `dtoday` to now have a column-label of `dg 77` but it's still `dg`, I need this to add week numbers to the standard column-labels of a spreadsheet I am creating.

Any help gratefully receieved :)

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a fault.
It does not appear to work when overriding it on the temp-table.

If you define your field in a frame before display then you can overide it there.

```
form tt-dg1.dtoday with frame f2.
tt-dg1.dtoday:label = "MyLabel".
display tt-dg1.dtoday with frame f2.
```

That may or not help depending on what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, I need to be able to set it in the temp-table as this is then being passed to the program that creates the multi-tabbed spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to dynamically create the temp table? if so you can dynamically set it there

```
DEFINE VARIABLE ttDynTable AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE vInt       AS INTEGER NO-UNDO INIT 77.

CREATE TEMP-TABLE ttDyntable.
ttDynTable:ADD-NEW-FIELD('dtoday', 'DATE', 0, "99/99/9999",?,"","dg " + STRING(vInt)).
ttDynTable:TEMP-TABLE-PREPARE("tt-dg1").

ttTTHandle = ttDyntable:DEFAULT-BUFFER-HANDLE.
ttTTHandle:BUFFER-CREATE.
ttTTHandle::dtoday = TODAY.

DISPLAY ttTTHandle:buffer-field('dtoday'):column-label ttTTHandle::dtoday.
```

if not you can just pull the column-label from the buffer instead

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt-dg1 FIELD dtoday AS DATE   COLUMN-LABEL "dg ". 
DEFINE VARIABLE   vTTHandle           AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
CREATE tt-dg1.
dtoday = TODAY.

vTTHandle = BUFFER tt-dg1:HANDLE.
vTTHandle:BUFFER-FIELD("dtoday"):column-LABEL = vTTHandle:BUFFER-FIELD("dtoday"):column-LABEL + "77".

DISPLAY vTTHandle:BUFFER-FIELD('dtoday'):COLUMN-LABEL.
```